# Return sum from specific column, group by 2 factors with a count

Tags: mysql

I apologize if my title is confusing, but here is my table structure/columns:

```
| ID  | category | year | events |
```

each `Category` has a handful of `ID`. The `year` column has 2010-2020. However, not all `ID` have a row for each `year`. There are no `ID` in multiple `category`, so each `category` has its own set of `ID`.

I want to `SUM(events)` and group by `category` and `year` where `ID` has a row for each `year` (e.g. count > 10, a row for each year 2010-2020).

In other words, my ideal output would be one row per `year` per `category`with the `SUM(events)`. The `ID` column doesn't matter, just the sum of all events for a given `category`.

Something like this:

```
 | CATEGORY | YEAR | EVENTS |
 | 003      | 2010 | 30     |
 | 003      | 2011 | 34     |
 | ...      | ...  | ...    |
 | 003      | 2020 | 23     |
 | 004      | 2010 | 10     |
 | 004      | 2011 | 22     |
 and so on
```

I have tried this to no avail:

```
SELECT category, ID, COUNT(year) as count, year, SUM(events) FROM table GROUP BY category HAVING count > 10
```

This just groups the sum of events for each ID which have more than 10 years of data. But I want to group by category per year.

thanks in advance and I hope my explanation is clearer than my title...

Comment: Can you please show the expected output.

Comment: It is under "something like this" in original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by both `year` and `category`

```
SELECT category, ID, COUNT(year) as count, year, SUM(events) 
FROM table GROUP BY year, category 
HAVING count > 10
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives me the same output. I feel like i might need to do a left join or something since I first need to figure out what ID have 11 rows, then sum their  events by category per year

Comment: please share the output you are getting and the output you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

To find difference between each CATEGORY's year, you can also use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function

Try this format,

```
SELECT category, ID, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ('first year of student') ,('second year of student')))  as count, year, SUM(events) FROM table GROUP BY category,year HAVING count > 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I get a blank return.

Comment: You should write a query for 'first year of student' to find First year. 
You should write a query for 'second year of student' to find Second year.